# Use PowerShell to obtain Office 365 DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell, mx-record, microsoft-office-365

For the past while, I’ve been learning PowerShell to administrate our Office 365 tenancy instead of using the web interface.

After adding a new domain and confirming ownership of the domain name (all done through PowerShell), I was wondering if there’s a cmdlet that can be used to obtain the zone records that should be configured for a domain that is to be managed by Office 365.

[Gather the information you need to create Office 365 DNS records](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Gather-the-information-you-need-to-create-Office-365-DNS-records-77f90d4a-dc7f-4f09-8972-c1b03ea85a67?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAACAAA=Step_2) explains how to obtain this information using the web interface but I’d prefer to do as much as possible using PowerShell.

At the moment, I can use the `Get-DkimSigningConfig` to determine the correct CNAME record to enable DKIM, e.g.,

```
Get-DkimSigningConfig -Identity contoso.com | fl Selector?CNAME
```

This should generally be of the form `selector1-contoso-com._domainkey.contoso.onmicrosoft.com` but I found that for one of our managed domains the DKIM CNAME had to be set to `selector1-contoso-com0i._domainkey.contoso.onmicrosoft.com` (an additional `0i`).

For the MX record, I’d expect it to be `contoso-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` but I’d like to be certain so I’m wondering if there’s a PowerShell cmdlet or Azure object that lists the DNS records that should be configured for a managed domain (in particular what to use for the MX record).

I spent a lot of time searching the web and Microsoft’s own documentation but I only found references to how to determine this information using the web interface.

Comment: FYI your guess on the MX record is off by one character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit late, but for future reference, this is now possible using the [AzureAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) module:

```
Get-AzureADDomainServiceConfigurationRecord -Name mydomain.com
```

Or if you want to get only the MX record:

```
(Get-AzureADDomainServiceConfigurationRecord -Name mydomain.com | `
           where RecordType -eq MX).MailExchange
```

You can also set the supported services for a newly added domain using:

```
Set-AzureADDomain -Name mydomain.com -SupportedServices Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline, Intune
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, since asking this question, I've changed jobs (to a Unix-only role) so I can't verify it. From a cursory look at the documentation, it looks like this will do the job so I've upvoted and accepted this answer. Hopefully, this can help others administer their Azure/365 tenancies.

Comment: I was able to use these commands and they work.  Thank you for the -SupportedServices argument.  That was what I was missing.